# coordianes unit in vector images. is that px also?

Tags: css, svg

whats the coordinate unit of the vector images (SVG) specially in CSS?
is that px? or something other?
i'm using border-image-slice, but i don't know how to use it when the border-image-source is setted on a vector image.

Comment: It's px unless you've applied transforms to scale/rotate/skew the contents.

Comment: to the context of what? of the image or the element?

Comment: the elements mainly, although you can introduce transforms by sizing the image differently to the underlying size.

Comment: what will be the unit after i applied transforms to scale/rotate/skew the contents?

Comment: Whatever you scaled/rotated it to. If you skew it it won't really have a unit.